# Django Foreign Key to a yet-to-be created Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm wondering if there's way in Django to associate a model to another, yet-to-be created model with a foreign key. Both model would be created using the same ModelForm in the same HTML page.

e.g.

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = forms.CharField
    ...

class Player(models.Model):
    name = forms.CharField()
    key = forms.ForeignKey(Team)
    ...
```

Basically, I'm wondering if both these models can be put in the same `<form>...</form>` in one HTML page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a foreign key is a reference to the primary key of the referenced model, so the target needs to exist. you need to save the first form, and then update the reference on the second one before saving. to get a model instance from a form without saving to the db, you can use

```
instance = form.save(commit=False)
```

you then need to save the instance yourself

```
instance.save()
```

and if you are using many-to-many fields, you need to look at `save_m2m`

Comment: How do I update the reference on the second one with the new ly saved model? Should I change something in the POST dict?

Comment: you can just edit the `instance` before saving it. e.g. `instance.team = instance2`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the documentation for [inlineformset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-an-inline-formset-in-a-view), it allows to edit the related objects of a model in the same view, also see [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/).

```
def manage_teams(request, team_id):
    team = Player.objects.get(pk=team_id)
    PlayerInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Player, Team)
    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = PlayerInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=team)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
           # Do something.
    else:
        formset = PlayerInlineFormSet(instance=team)
    return render_to_response("manage_teams.html", {
        "formset": formset,
})
```

Here goes another example:

```
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
def new_team(request):
    PlayerInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Team, Player)
    team= Team()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_team = TeamForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance= team, prefix= 'team')
        form_player = PlayerInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance= team, prefix= 'players')
        if form_team.is_valid() and form_player.is_valid():
            form_team.save()
            form_player.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/teams/%s/' % team.slug)
    else:
        form_team = TeamForm( instance= team,  prefix= 'team')
        form_player = PlayerInlineFormSet(instance= team, prefix= 'players')
    return render_to_response('Teams/new_team.html', {'form_team': form_team, 'form_player':form_player}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer :). I got it working using second's method, but I'll definitely look up formsets.