# A correct case to use Django signals

Tags: django, django-signals

*I have a global question and a question about a specific problem in a context of signals.* In order to solve what the issues, signal dispatcher is most useful, overkill?

I have an issue of saving multiple modelforms with foreign key. I assumed that this a signal can solve it. But I can't get how, because I do not understand the scope of the signals.

**model**

```
class CV(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # And other fields...

class HigherEducation(models.Model):
    cv = models.ForeignKey(CV, blank=True, null=True)
    institution = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # And other fields...

class ProfessionalExperience(models.Model):
    cv = models.ForeignKey(CV, blank=True, null=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # And other fields...
```

All the forms are modelforms inherited from models above. The last two are used in modelformsets. All of this forms are displayed in one html form in template.

**forms**

```
class CVForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        # All the stuff

class EducationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        # All the stuff

class ExperienceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        # All the stuff

Education = modelformset_factory(HigherEducation, 
                                 form=EducationForm,
                                 max_num=2)
Experience = modelformset_factory(ProfessionalExperience,
                                  form=ExperienceForm,
                                  max_num=1)
```

In the view I need to save the `EducationForm` and `ExperienceForm` with `cv` field with the assigned ID of current `CV` model.

**Can I solve this problem by signals?**

*It was hard to formulate the problem, so if anything is not clear, I will edit the question.*

Comment: don't think you need signals. have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107751/django-foreign-key-to-a-yet-to-be-created-model/8107770#8107770

Comment: [My formula to work with business rules](http://beutil.blogspot.com/2011/10/django-moving-business-rules-from-views.html)

Comment: One day I will get round to writing my blog entry "Things in Django you should never use: Part 2, Signals". (Part 1 is model inheritance, BTW).

Comment: @DanielRoseman please, share your expertise. I have an application running in this way without issues. How can I do it better? I can overwrite save and clean instead to use signals if this is a best solution!

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ha, I use Signals and model inheritence all the time; they're indispensable for large-scale applications where actions can happen on many different areas of the site. `django-notification` (https://github.com/jtauber/django-notification) is an example of an almost wholly Signals-based app that I add to every project I create.

Comment: @danihp, JordanReiter I was being more than slightly facetious, of course. They have their place, but are prone to being misunderstood - with signals, for example, people often think they're somehow executed outside the request/response cycle, which of course they're not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Signals are simply hooks that allow you to fire pieces of code after a particular action occurs, i.e. 'when an instance/row of a model `Foo` is saved, run the function `baz()`'. Signals have two components : the [actual signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#defining-and-sending-signals) (the action that has been carried out - a save/delete etc.) and the [receiving function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#receiver-functions) (what to do when that action occurs).

Django has many signals built in (for example, that is fired [after](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) or [before](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save) a save operation, a signal that is fired after or before a delete operation) but you can also create your own signals. If you had a signup process in your website, you could write a signal that fires when a user creates an account and then link that signal to a function that sends the user an email

I don't think your situation is related to using signals. It sounds to me like you want to create a single form (composed of 3 smaller forms) where the latter 2 forms (Education & Experience) rely on the previous form (CV) being saved first?

In this case the issue is that you can't fill out the 2nd and 3rd form without having filled out the 1st form first (as no CV will exist yet) so to achieve this you might be best creating a [form wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) with 3 steps; first save the CV, then using the CV show the 2nd and 3rd steps (which at this stage the CV will already be saved)